# Append data to form using through DOM?

Tags: laravel, alpine.js

Form which uses POST method:

```
<div>
<form action="{{ route('post.store') }}" method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="name">
   <input type="text" name="text">
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
@foreach ($comments as $comment)
   {{ $comment->text }}
   <a href="#">Reply</a>
@endforeach
</div>
```

Array of `$comments` is being returned when the view itself is returned.

Basically, I am intrested if there is a way to append `$comment->id` to the data that will be sent to server on `Submit` button click using Laravel Blade or AlpineJS, but without creating any additional functions between `<script>` tags? I mean, is it possible to do something like this: `<a href="#" @click.prevent="formData.append('parent_comment_id', {{ $comment->id }})">Reply</a>`?

**EDIT:**

I expressed myself wrongly. I don't want to append new `id` every time `Reply` is clicked, but to overwrite corresponding property in data which is going to be sent to server when `Submit` button is clicked with the `$comment->id` for which `Reply` was clicked  for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using [Laravel Resource Controller](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#resource-controllers)

Not sure I totally understand why you want to send all *comment ids* when submitting the form but when calling the route `post.store` you should better send the post id

```php
<form action="{{ route('post.store', ['post' => $post]) }}" method="POST">
```

If you want to get all comment id and have proper [model relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships) set up in your models you can get all comments for a post in your controller.

To send a specific id in your form create a new `<input name="comment_id" value="">` and let that field be populated.

Comment: No no, I want to send only one `$comment` id, the one for which the `Reply` was clicked. I mean, I could use an `<input>` which I could hide and set it's value ones `Reply` is clicked, otherways set it to 0, but is there a cleaner way?

Comment: Fine, `input` it is then